# Replacing not working string Bukkit

Tags: java

I have a string args[1] + args[2] + message but if I do

```
    String message = args[1] + args[2] + message;
    message.replace(args[1], "").replace(args[2], "");
```

Comment: Look up the documentation! String instances are invariant and cannot be changed. The replace() method RETURNS  a new string with the replacement accomplished.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this String message? currently you create a string with args[1] + args[2] + message and after your replace calls you'll get back your original message. why are you doing this?

Comment: For a message when ban and tempbans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) of the `replace` method it says that it *returns* the modified `String`. A `String` is immutable and cannot be changed directly. You have to resolve the new `String` back to the variable:

```
message = message.replace(args[1], "").replace(args[2], "");
```